# JOIN 2 ух DataTable

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, linq, ado.net

На вход подается 2 DataTable, которые имеют одинаковые структуры.

Название и кол-во колонок в DataTable'ах заранее неизвестно.

Как мне соединить между собой 2 DataTable по первичному ключу(он может быть составным), а на выходе получить список из колонок обоих DataTable-ов?

**UPD**

Нашел решение в виде создания DataRelation

```
      static void CmpData(DataTable newDT, DataTable oldDT)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("test");
        newDT.TableName= newDT.TableName + "_new";
        oldDT.TableName = oldDT.TableName + "_old";
        ds.Tables.AddRange(new[] { newDT, oldDT });
        DataRelation drel = new DataRelation("rel", newDT.PrimaryKey, oldDT.PrimaryKey, false);

        ds.Relations.Add(drel);
        Console.WriteLine("LINQ");
        foreach (DataRow row in newDT.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.GetChildRows("rel").Length > 0&&x["t3"].ToString()!= x.GetChildRows("rel")[0]["t3"].ToString()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}->{1}", row[0], row.GetChildRows("rel")[0][0]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("OTHER");
        foreach (DataRow row in newDT.Rows)
        {
            if (row.GetChildRows("rel").Length != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}->{1}", row[0], row.GetChildRows("rel")[0][0]);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("{0}->null", row[0]);
        }
    }
```

В итоге получается довольно динамическая штуковина. Там где `GetChildRows==0`, значит произошло добавление или удаление. Можно перебирать столбцы, даже с помощью LINQ можно строчки отбирать.

Другой вопрос насколько это производительнее решения, где я делаю прямые запросы к БД....

**UPD2**

Потестил решение. Довольно быстро работает.
Единственный минус, так это , если придется сравнивать здоровенные базы, то беда будет с потреблением оперативки. На маленьких базах довольно хорошо работает.

Comment: Эмм... а точно нужен join а не union? просто совпадение структур таблиц обычно нужно для union, а для join не имеет значения

Comment: Мне потребуется выявлять изменения между колонками одного DataTable и другого. Т.е один DataTable до каких-либо изменений(От старой Access базы), другой новый (От измененной Access Базы)

Comment: Не могли бы вы включить в вопрос чуть больше информации о том, что должно быть на выходе? т.е. результат операции - таблица с удвоенным числом столбцов?

Comment: Вы правильно поняли. Я хочу получить результат классического INNER JOIN. List<T>, который содержит колонки из обоих DataTable.

Comment: Сейчас я выявил 2 проблемы: 1) Непонятно как динамически генерить строчку соединения таблиц, если ключ составной. 2)Field и тип, как я понимаю должен определяться на этапе компиляции. Пытался подсунуть DataType и компилятор ругается... Решаемая ли моя задачи вообще? Использовал AsEnumerable.

Comment: как раз перекапываю маны, пока нашел только это https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326080, на EnSO советовали http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379747/create-combined-datatable-from-two-datatables-joined-with-linq-c-sharp

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37232/discussion-between-rdorn-and-iluxa1810).